# Code-igniter href duplicate base url

Tags: codeigniter

```
<li><a href="<?php echo site_url('home'); ?>">Home</a></li>
```

that give to me `localhost/farmex/localhost/farmex/home`

and suppose to be  `localhost/farmex/home`

Comment: at config.php set your base_url like this `$config['base_url'] = 'http:/localhost/farmex/';`

Comment: @ShaifulIslam thanks that helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`base_url` need to set to get proper link from `site_url` function.

At your application/config.php you need to set

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http:/localhost/farmex/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Remember `$config['index_page']` is also important.

If you set

```
  $config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

`site_url('home')` will produce `http:/localhost/farmex/index.php/home`

`$config['index_page'] = 'index.php?';` will produce `http:/localhost/farmex/index.php?/home` which is needed sometimes.like if you don't want to use .htaccess file.

Answer (score 1):

in routes.php you can set `$route['default_controller'] = 'home';` and change your code to 
`<li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>">Home</a></li>`
Hope this help! ^^